# julia broadcasting (equivalent of numpy newaxis)

Tags: julia

```
using Distance

 euclidean ([1:10;1:10], [1:10])
ERROR: DimensionMismatch("The lengths of a and b must match.")
 in get_common_len at /home/nbecker/.julia/v0.4/Distance/src/common.jl:11
 in sumsqdiff at /home/nbecker/.julia/v0.4/Distance/src/metrics.jl:40
 in euclidean at /home/nbecker/.julia/v0.4/Distance/src/metrics.jl:83
```

How would I force broadcasting here, in a space and time efficient manner?
I believe numpy would use newaxis for this.

Comment: This is just a matter of missing functionality from the Distance package – it won't automatically do broadcasting, but it could. I would suggest opening an issue that requests the addition of this.

Comment: Note that in many cases, you can use the excellent built-in [`broadcast`](http://docs.julialang.org/en/release-0.3/stdlib/arrays/#Base.broadcast) and `broadcast!` functions.  They are very efficient.  Unfortunately, they don't work for this case since they operate over the arrays elementwise, whereas `euclidean` needs to operate over vectors.

Comment: Has this functionality since been added to Distances.jl?

Answer (score 1):

Why do you want to use broadcasting necessarily? You can accomplish the same thing using `repmat()`:

```
euclidean([1:10;1:10], repmat([1:10],2))
```

Comment: Doesn't repmat allocate?